# bringToFront doesn't work correctly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view, android-button

I created a custom view and put about 14 `EditText` on it. I wanted to change the position of one of `EditText`, so at first I used `editText.bringToFront();` then I changed the position of this button with the Index of this `EditText`   `getChildAt(childIndex).setY(y);`. I was surprised when I saw that all the `EditTexts` that their index is upper than this button are moving. I don't know why `bringToFront` method change the index of other `EditTexts`.

Simplified source code with `Button` (Not `EditText`). This works correctly without `bringToFront()` . But I want To use `EditText`:

```
public class CustomView extends ViewGroup{

private int height;
private int childCount;
int chosenIndex;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    childCount = getChildCount();
    height = 200;

    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childCount; childIndex++) {
        Button child = (Button) getChildAt(childIndex);
        child.layout(l, childIndex * height, r, (childIndex + 1) * height);
        child.setText("" + childIndex);
    }
}

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

    float y = ev.getY();

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                if (getChildAt(i).getY() < y && getChildAt(i).getY() + getChildAt(i).getHeight() > y) {
                    chosenIndex = i;
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // No bringToFront()
                getChildAt(chosenIndex).setY(y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                getChildAt(chosenIndex).setY(y);
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Source Code with `EditText` (The Problem is here, this doesn't work with `bringToFront()` or without it)

```
public class CustomView extends ViewGroup{

private int height;
private int childCount;
int chosenIndex;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    childCount = getChildCount();
    height = 200;

    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childCount; childIndex++) {
        EditText child = (EditText) getChildAt(childIndex);
        child.layout(l, childIndex * height, r, (childIndex + 1) * height);
        int color = Color.rgb(childIndex * 40, 0, 0);
        child.setBackgroundColor(color);
        child.setText("" + childIndex);
    }
}

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

    float y = ev.getY();

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                if (getChildAt(i).getY() < y && getChildAt(i).getY() + getChildAt(i).getHeight() > y) {
                    chosenIndex = i;
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            getChildAt(chosenIndex).bringToFront();   // Here is the problem with BringToFront
            getChildAt(chosenIndex).setY(y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            getChildAt(chosenIndex).setY(y);
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you testing it on Android version >= `lollipop`?

Comment: yes. on lollipop. but it is the same on android version 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably due to the `elevation` parameter (it's present on >= `Lollipop` versions).

Try this:

1. Set `ViewCompat.setElevation(btn, 0);` on all of your `Buttons`
2. **Not only** call `btn.bringToFront()` but **also** `ViewCompat.setElevation(btn, someLargerThanZeroValue)` when you want to move your `Button` above others.

Comment: Nothing changed after try this steps. Actually when I call `btn.bringToFront()` the index of all childs (buttons) changes to index of `btn`. So all the childs move, when I change the position of `btn`

Comment: I changed some thing in the source. Please see that.